# Diametric vs Diametrical vs Diametral

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

What are the nuances in the difference between the meanings of these words? When is it okay to consider them interchangeable? In what cases one of them is clearly more valid than the others?

Answer (score 2):

The only one of the three I ever remember encountering is *diametric*.

I see the other two are listed in the OED; but unless they have technical meanings in some field, I would regard them as obsolete.